playerctl not detecting Opera browser downloaded from Snap as an audio player
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

WM: i3 (with polybar)
I used to use the Opera browser downloaded from Opera's website as a .deb package, but there were several issues with that 'variant' of Opera, some being: inability to play some YouTube videos, inability to play Twitch streams, etc.. So, I did my research and found out that using Opera downloaded from Snap will have all these issues resolved, and so I removed the .deb Opera, and installed Opera from Snap (sudo snap install opera) and it resolved all my issues, but it created a new one.
playerctl was earlier able to detect all the audio playing in my Opera, i.e. it detected Opera as a player. I was able to control the browser audio using it by binding some keys to playerctl commands in my i3-config, and also was able to display audio information in my Polybar using some scripts. But since I've started using the 'better', Snap version of Opera, playerctl does no longer detect it as a player, thus disabling me from controlling any of the browser playback. I thought it was some MPRIS issue, so i ran dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged'" (ChatGPT helped me with that) to see if Opera was even sending MPRIS signals or not, and it was sending the player signals.
What seems to be the issue here? How do I fix it? Since this is my first post here, I tried my best explaining everything, but if I miss something, do ask me in the comments.

nice investigation! kudos.

thanks @MarcusMüller :)
there are several other things i noticed, the most noticeable one being that if i run opera in the command prompt, i get this snap version of opera (current one) where videos work fine and playerctl fails. this runs opera that is present in the /snap/bin, interestingly, if i go deep into /snap/opera/314/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera, and run the opera present there (/snap/opera/314/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera), i get my old, broken opera back! yes, the opera which playerctl detects! and its a completely new session where the entire browser is reset!

yeah that is not surprising
